# Can I make a cell be in editing mode all the time?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a UITableView with one section. The last row it to add new objects, and it reads "Add Object".

How can I make this cell stay in editing mode so that it will always show the plus icon? I've tried using cell.editing = YES and [cell setEditing:YES animated:NO] but neither makes the cell appear in editing mode.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Implement delegate's

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method. You might also need to set tableview's editing property to YES, but I am not sure.

Comment: yes, you will need to set it to YES. and unfortunately, that can lead to a large switch statement if you've got a lot of sections and rows to make look/behave different.